# Is a shared cart possible in a multi-store with multi-domain [v1.9]?

Tags: multistore

I have a single Magento install that hosts several stores, each with their own domain and catalog but under the same main brand.

What my client want's to achieve is a way for all the stores to share a single cart. For example; 
I add a product in store A and then add a product in store B. 
I could then checkout at either store A or B and pay for both products.

I stumbled across this post where Marius [refers to his blog](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/392/is-it-possible-to-share-the-cart-contents-between-multi-store-websites) with a solution. [link to the blog](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.nl/2013/01/share-cart-between-websites.html)

From the comments I gather this is working for most but for me things don't seem to change. If I add something to the cart in website A and then visit website B the cart is empty.

Hope you guys have some suggestions, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can not share Customer Carts with Multi domain web site.